# XSL transformation for file .docx

Tags: xslt, ms-word, docx

My question is, is it possible to apply XSLT to .docx file without saving it as XML through the tab "Save As" in the MS Word. And if it possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

As I know .docx it's only ziped folder with number of *.xml files, the files contains the document content, styles, headers, footnotes and so on. So all you need is unzip your .docx and apply your XSLT to particular xml (suppose it's document.xml for the content).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, a docx file is infact a zip file. If you rename it to zip  you can even navigate into it using the Windows Explorer. Having that you just unzip the file and execute XSLT against its contents.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But my situation is that I have a folder in which to store a large number of files with the extension .docx and you want to apply to each conversion. And take every file, rename it to the zip, it can get crazy, if files pieces 100. Is it possible for example to use as a xslt without producing any manipulations with the file .docx.

Comment: What framework are you using? If it is .NET then you can create your custom XML resolver. The idea is that your XML resolver would actually accept docx files, runtime inmemory extract it and provide the needed XML for the upstream XSLT transform.

Comment: Wow, that's great. And how to do it, advise, please, to read on the subject, what to look for? Thank you so much

Comment: The XSLT tranform class ctor among the many overloads takes arguments that are not an XML document but rather an XMLResolver. Here you provide your own subclass (inherited from...) of XMLResolver that does what I described above... do you need to know more?